# How to tell someone that we can't imply an equation to another equation as to when multiplying $x$ both sides?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question

So my friends and I was trying to tell someone that this implication is wrong, he (that person) said that these equations are the same:

$$9x = 1 \Rightarrow 3x^2 = \frac x3$$

He confused why $9x = 1 \Rightarrow x={1/9, 0}$ isn't true. You see that the second one of the solutions is $x=0$, that obviously multiplying both sides with $0$ isn't wise. I was trying to explain that by fundamental theorem of algebra the first equation only has $1$ solution, but he's too obtuse to accept that and I gave up. In my real analysis class, we also had someone that doing this he thought it was legal.

If I don't mistakenly remember, it's about solving absolute equations, or whatever you call it, he suggested multiplying both sides with $0$ and that led him into wrong answers different set of solutions. My answer, however, avoiding multiplying both sides with $0$ and using basic axioms led me into correct answer which is, in my opinion, multiplying both sides with an unknown variable is really dangerous. It's really shameful I can't remember the exact problem to illustrate this.

Anyway, related to the question, how to explain this problem?

Comment: The most straightforward way to describe this problem is that for any functions of a real variable (or a variable of any field) $f(x) = g(x)$ is equivalent to $xf(x) = xg(x)$ **or** $x = 0$. If you drop the "or $x = 0$" your statements are no longer logically equivalent.

Comment: Wait a second. Are you saying your friend believes $x=0$ is a solution to $9x=1$? If that is so, I have no idea how to help. If a person thinks $9x=1$ is true for $x=0$ there is a more fundamental issue here. -- If, on the other hand, your friend accepts that $x=0$ is *not* a solution to $9x=1$, but is a solution to $3x^2=x/3$, and they are only confused about why it is a solution to one but not the other, then one can start explaining ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg it's the second issue I think. but I'm also not sure whether they believe the first issue that you mentioned.

Comment: You should clarify that first. As said, unless a person sees clearly that $x=0$ is a solution to the second equation but not to the first (even if they are puzzled *why*), any argument involving algebra or logic is totally in vain.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I've re-read his question. It was actually posted on Facebook. He really thinks both equations are exactly the same, that's why he thinks $x=0$ must be true.

Comment: Let me put it this way: If a person posts on Facebook that he believes $x=0$ is a solution to $9x=1$, nothing that anyone on math.stackexchange writes will make him understand he's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $9x=1\implies 3x^2=\frac{x}{3}$. Since $3x^2=\frac{x}{3}\iff x\in\{0,\frac{1}{9}\}$, it is also true that $9x=1\implies x\in\{0,\frac{1}{9}\}$.

However, I believe you're friend might think that this implies that $x=0$ is somehow a solution to $9x=1$. However, that is a logically flawed statement. What we would need to do is substitute $x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{9}$ independently to determine which ones were actual solutions. And we come up with that $x=\frac{1}{9}$ is the only solution to $9x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Does ${0\times 3 = 0\times 5 = 0}$ imply ${3 = 5}$? No, since we would be dividing by $0$. Consider
$$
x\times (3x) = x\times \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
Just like our obviously wrong ${3=5}$ , if ${x=0}$ we cannot conclude ${3x = \frac{1}{3}}$.